# Why does noise-figure of components become less significant further down the chain in a cascaded network?

Tags: rf, signal, noise, microwave

I understand mathematically why this happens, but I can't intuitively get my head round this idea.

To clarify this is the cascaded noise figure equation:

[image: cascaded noise figure]

Comment: Because the first stage input noise is amplified by every stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the gains from the inputs of each stage to the output.  This is assuming a chain of amplifier stages.  The input of the first stage gets multiplied by the gain of all stages together.  The input of each further stage only by the gain of the remaining stages.

For example, you have a microphone amplifier with overall gain of 2000, where the first stage has a voltage gain of 10 and produces a low impedance output.  The signal out of that stage (and into the remaining stages) is now less susceptible to noise for two reasons:

The impedance is lower.  Capacitively coupled noise has high impedance because it's in series with a relatively small capacitor, usually well under 100 pF.  The impedance of the signal forms a voltage divider with this capacitor.  The lower the impedance of the signal, the more the same capacitively coupled noise is attenuated getting to that signal.

There is less gain from this point to the output.  In this example, the gain is 10x less than what the raw microphone signal undergoes.  This is because noise injected after the first stage isn't amplified by that stage.  In this example, noise after the first stage is only amplified by 200 to the output.

Answer (score 1):

This only applies where the nominal signal level increases from stage to stage. This is usually the case where noise figure is often quoted, like in a receiver.

In a signal generator, where an attenuator is often part of the signal chain, noise figure becomes more significant later in the chain.

Noise figure is only one part of *Dynamic Range*, the real limitation to the performance of signal processing systems. Dynamic Range is given by the maximum signal level less the noise figure.

When noise figure is quoted by itself, we are usually making some assumptions about the signal levels. These assumptions may be valid, but sometimes are not.

For the front end of a sensitive receiver, if we make the assumption that the signal level is small, then noise figure is the only thing we need to worry about. As the signal level increases stage by stage, the 'headroom' between the signal and the added noise increases, so we can tolerate more added noise in later stages which have more signal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a noise plot from Signal Chain Explorer. The 3 OpAmps have gain of 10,10,10. The gain-set resistors, and the internal Rnoise_density, are scaled up by 100. Notice the noise contributions are exactly equal. Total is 9.4 uV
[image]

Here is the schematic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjPVRD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is unequally weighted lownoise design: still gain of 10x per stage, but resistors are scaled up by 10:  10 Ohm, 100 Ohm, 1Kohm. Total noise is 6.4 uV.
[image]

Thus that stage gain is your friend, your degree-of-freedom.

Time to run through a low-noise design, where the FIRST STAGE DOMINATES.
Assume need 1nanoVolt/RtHz noise density (60 ohms Rnoise).
Allocate 40 ohms total to the first stage of gain. 
[we'll use 20 Ohms ReferredToInput for 2nd stage, 1 Ohm RTI for 3rd]
And set up that first stage for gain of 5.

Note the 2nd stage has 1/25 the impact on the front-end noise. 
You can have 20 Ohms * 25 == 500 ohms of total noise generation 
in that 2nd stage. Set up that 2nd stage for gain of 10.

Note the 3rd stage has 1/100 *1/25 = 1/2,500 the impact on the 1rst stage.
We used up our front-end noise budget: 60 ohms = 40 + 20.
Design the 3rd stage for total noise resistors of 1,000 ohms.
Those scale down by 1,000/2,500 or less than 1 ohm at the first stage.

By the way, you can use the free tool Signal Chain Explorer to tinker with
these effects. Find SCE at robustcircuitdesign.com and let us know how you use it.

Another example: Set up the Signal Chain as

1) some opamp, with Rnoise of 30 ohms, Rg of 8 ohms and Rfb of 32 ohms (gain=5)

2) some opamp, with Rnoise of 400 ohms, Rg of 90 ohms and Rfb of 909 ohms(gain=10)

3) some opamp, with Rnoise of 900 ohms, Rg of 90 ohms and Rfb of 909 ohm(gain=10)

You may wonder why the LowPassFilter on output node. Necessary for identical noise contributions, because the first stage high-frequency noise is filtered differently from stage #3, unless we artificially constrain the high-freq noise.

Comment: Forgot to thank you for putting alot of effort into your answer, which is very good and hopefully helps other people reading my question however the answer I chose just spoke to me more in a way I could more easily understand, thanks again!